# Create a stopwatch (not a countdown or timer) without using Tk python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a stopwatch function for my module. It is to record the time that my module is called to be imported to the time that it is fully imported. The reason I am trying to record this is because my module takes forever to load (Because it needs to compile data from external sources and combine this data into lists). Forever being about 90 seconds. I have looked up similar questions but it would simply be about creating countdowns or timers. I'm open to many options, as long as they utilize python's built-in modules. If there's already something out there like this, it would be great if you can tell me. Thanks in advance!

If you need any more information, just leave a comment and I'll get back to you. :)

EDIT:

Taking into consideration MeetTitan's answer, I have made this test function to try this out:

```
def f():
    import time
    starttime = time.time()
    import tms # This is my module that takes forever to load
    print("Time Taken {}".format(int(time.clock() - starttime)))

>>> f()
Loading module. This may take up to 60 seconds.
Time taken -1419389848 # What does this mean?
```

Here's what it says in the Python Documentation:

time.clock()

On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very definition of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function of the same name, but in any case, this is the function to use for benchmarking Python or timing algorithms.

time.time()

Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number. Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second. While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has been set back between the two calls.

Is the output number supposed to be negative? What's the real time that it had taken? I'm sorry if I'm asking too many questions...

EDIT:

I've got it.

```
def f():
    import time
    start time = time.time()
    import tms
    print("Time taken {}".format(int(time.clock() - starttime)))
```

Now, here's my last issue. How do I integrate it within my existing code so that when I type in this:

```
>>> import tms
Loading module. This may take up to 60 seconds. # after 30 seconds...
Time taken 31.49 seconds
```

this is the beginning of my code:

```
import os, sys, time

# Does the code go somewhere here? How would I implement it?

print("Loading module. This may take up to 60 seconds.

tmlist = []
alltmlist = []
gen1tmlist = []
gen2tmlist = []
```

I've made a follow-up question in hope of my "ideas" getting out more effectively. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639658/record-time-taken-to-import-module).

Comment: `time.clock()` is deprecated to my knowledge. You also mixed `time.clock()` and `time.time()`  which wouldn't output anything logical.  If negative values persist, is the absolute value correct? If so use it.

Comment: Take a look at my edit, I had a typo. :-( Re copy and paste and you'll be good :-). Even though `time.clock()` is deprecated, I like it. You may choose to use whichever you like more, or provides the best resolution on your system. But remember if you do `startTime = time.time()` you must do `time.time() - startTime`, or vice versa.

Comment: Generally not a good idea to put all the processing at top level, that is run at import time. But it in a function that is called by a script after it's imported. Then you can easily alter, test, and inspect what is going on.

Comment: Should I re-ask this question on a separate page? I think that from the very beginning the point of what I was trying to accomplish did not get through. And Keith, I want my module to say the time it took to be imported, I don't want to be make separate functions and scripts, and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to time a snippet, the `time.time()` method is what you're after. Try this:

```
startTime = time.time()
#long running code here
print "Time taken {}".format(time.time() - startTime)
```

Also take a look at [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).

If an actual countdown is what you're after, you could try sleeping for n seconds until you get to 90, like so:

```
timeTotal = 0
timeResolution = 0.5
waitUntil = 90
while timeTotal < waitUntil:
    time.sleep(timeResolution)
    timeTotal += timeResolution
    print "\r{} seconds left".format(waitUntil - timeTotal),
```

Comment: @Zizouz212, just edited, this should be better. You can set time resolution to wait for different times for better resolution.

Comment: I don't know if the second edit is answering my question. Now I have to wait 90 seconds before my module imports (why I was avoiding `time.sleep` since I believe it halts all the code that is being executed). Also, it doesn't always take 90 seconds, sometimes 45, sometimes 30. And I'm looking for a stopwatch to record the time that it took to import the module, not a countdown or timer... Sorry about that.

Comment: Put that in a separate thread so you don't block the import :) And if you want to record time a snippet takes, take a look at the top part of my answer. That explains it.

Answer (score 1):

If a line of data is enough to showing your stopwatch, how about to rewrite a line on console by using 'carriage return' character "\r"?

Following code is simple countdown timer displays 100 to 0 at a fixed (not scrolled) line.

```
import sys, time
for num in range(100,0,-1):
    sys.stdout.write("\r    \r%d" % num)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The point is, write white spaces at first then write data you want.

In above code, "\r    " is white spaces part, and "\r%d" is data part.